# Savon gem error message : Unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: ruby, soap, rubygems, savon

I am getting 'unable to get local issuer certificate'  error messagewhen calling https SOAP service using savon 2.3.3.

URL: https://igeneration.irishvoip.com/a2billing/webservice/SOAP/soap-a2billing-server.php?wsdl

I have generated local cert using openssl with this steps :
1.openssl genrsa -out privkey.pem 1024
2.openssl req -new -key privkey.pem -out certreq.csr
3.openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in certreq.csr -signkey privkey.pem -out newcert.pem
4.password : 'test'
5.Copy both certs locally to /Users/will/code/igen-service/lib/ folder (project is under  /Users/will/code/igen-service/) folder.

```
module IGenSoapService
API_KEY = '2345sef9034WE51mFGzc42354'

def self.md5
  Digest::MD5.hexdigest(API_KEY)
end

def self.service
  # create a client for the service
  client = Savon.client(wsdl: 'https://igeneration.irishvoip.com/a2billing/webservice/SOAP/soap-a2billing-server.php?wsdl',
                        ssl_cert_file: "/Users/will/code/igen-service/lib/newcert.pem",
                        ssl_cert_key_file: "/Users/will/code/igen-service/lib/privkey.pem",
                        ssl_cert_key_password: "test",
                        log_level: :debug,
                        log: true,
                        )

  #ap -> awesome_print gem
  ap client.operations
  md5_api = md5()

  response = client.call(:get_calls_history_igen) do
    message security_key: md5_api, did:6796008000, secret:598859, starttime_begin:'2014/03/01', starttime_end:'2014/09/01', offset:0 ,items_number:100
  end
  ap response

end
```

end

Rake spec results

```
    'awesome_print' /Users/will/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby -S rspec    ./spec/example_spec.rb --color --format progress
    D, [2014-09-22T00:39:03.986248 #74682] DEBUG -- : HTTPI GET request to     igeneration.irishvoip.com (httpclient)
    at depth 0 - 20: unable to get local issuer certificate

[
    [ 0] :update_currencies_list,
    [ 1] :reload_asterisk_sip_iax,
    [ 2] :authenticate_admin,
    [ 3] :set_admin_pwd,
    [ 4] :write_notification,
    [ 5] :create_instance,
    [ 6] :set_instance_description,
    [ 7] :set_instance_provisioning,
    [ 8] :get_customer_groups,
    [ 9] :get_currencies,
    [10] :get_currencies_value,
    [11] :get_countries,
    [12] :get_setting,
    [13] :set_setting,
    [14] :get_account_attribute,
    [15] :set_account_attribute,
    [16] :get_languages,
    [17] :create_did_group,
    [18] :create_provider,
    [19] :create_ratecard,
    [20] :create_callplan,
    [21] :create_voucher,
    [22] :create_customer,
    [23] :validate_did_prefix,
    [24] :create_did,
    [25] :get_provisioning_list,
    [26] :create_trunk_config,
    [27] :get_rates,
    [28] :create_rates,
    [29] :update_rates,
    [30] :get_subscription_signup,
    [31] :add_caller_id,
    [32] :get_calls_history,
    [33] :get_log_refill,
    [34] :add_credit,
    [35] :get_calls_history_igen,
    [36] :check_did_igen,
    [37] :check_mailbox_igen,
    [38] :get_country_code_igen,
    [39] :get_country_codes_all_igen,
    [40] :get_account_attribute_igen,
    [41] :get_balance_igen,
    [42] :add_credit_igen,
    [43] :get_rate_igen,
    [44] :create_did_igen_single,
    [45] :create_customer_igen_single,
    [46] :update_customer_igen_single,
    [47] :delete_customer_igen_single,
    [48] :change_customer_did_igen,
    [49] :get_voicemail_pin_igen,
    [50] :set_voicemail_pin_igen,
    [51] :get_sip_secret_igen,
    [52] :set_sip_secret_igen
]
I, [2014-09-22T00:39:06.939992 #74682]  INFO -- : SOAP request: https://igeneration.irishvoip.com/a2billing/webservice/SOAP/soap-a2billing-server.php
I, [2014-09-22T00:39:06.940070 #74682]  INFO -- : SOAPAction: "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/#IGEN_SOAP_A2Billing#Get_Calls_History_IGEN", Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8, Content-Length: 555
D, [2014-09-22T00:39:06.940113 #74682] DEBUG -- : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="urn:Billing" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Body><tns:Get_Calls_History_IGEN><securityKey>c86c39b9b5ca5bce7441f7a7e8d864a7</securityKey><did>6796008000</did><secret>598859</secret><starttimeBegin>2014/03/01</starttimeBegin><starttimeEnd>2014/09/01</starttimeEnd><offset>0</offset><itemsNumber>100</itemsNumber></tns:Get_Calls_History_IGEN></env:Body></env:Envelope>
D, [2014-09-22T00:39:06.940669 #74682] DEBUG -- : HTTPI POST request to igeneration.irishvoip.com (httpclient)
at depth 0 - 20: unable to get local issuer certificate
I, [2014-09-22T00:39:08.567002 #74682]  INFO -- : SOAP response (status 500)
D, [2014-09-22T00:39:08.567111 #74682] DEBUG -- : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
 xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
 SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
<faultcode xsi:type="xsd:QName">SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring xsi:type="xsd:string">method &quot;urn:BillingGet_Calls_History_IGEN&quot; not defined in service</faultstring>
<faultactor xsi:type="xsd:anyURI"></faultactor>
<detail xsi:type="xsd:string"></detail></SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

F

Failures:

  1) IGenApiService IGenSOAPService#call API
     Failure/Error: response = Service::IGenSoapService.service()
     Savon::SOAPFault:
       (SOAP-ENV:Server) method "urn:BillingGet_Calls_History_IGEN" not defined in service
     # ./lib/igen_service.rb:86:in `service'
     # ./spec/example_spec.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Can anyone help ?